# What's the -Wsomething flag for 'instance method not found' warnings?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, warnings, clang

I recently had a case where someone added a parameter to an init method and broke another project that shared the code. Since it's only a warning, nobody realized the app was broken, so I'm trying to turn only this warning into an error:

```
warning: instance method '-someMethod' not found (return type defaults to 'id')
```

I've found that you can pass -Werror=foo in Other C Flags to the compiler in Xcode to turn a warning into the error, but I can't seem to find what 'foo' should be. I've tried 'undeclared-selectors' but that only catches @selector cases. I've tried -Werror-implicit-function-declaration but that doesn't seem to catch that case either.

I tried 'inst-method-not-found' and 'instance-method-not-found' after finding 'warn_inst_method_not_found' during a casual search of the huge clang source code.

Help ... ?

**Update:**
Here's an example you can compile (e.g. in CodeRunner) to see the warning: https://gist.github.com/4045701

Comment: Not an answer but can you not just make sure your code throws no warnings and treat all warnings as errors?

Comment: You can switch on warnings as errors globally with 

GCC_TREAT_WARNINGS_AS_ERRORS = YES ("Treat Warnings As Errors") but i suspect you dont want all warnings as errs

Comment: “Since it's only a warning, nobody realized the app was broken…” This is the reason to treat *all* warnings as errors.

Comment: The best I can think of is to use -Werror (which turns **all** warnings into errors, including this one) and then -Wno-error=<warningflag> for **every single type of warning** that you don't want as an error.

Comment: Treat All Warnings As Errors doesn't work. It's a Carbon project. The entire app would stop compiling due to "deprecated" warnings.

Comment: pmjordan, yeah, that sounds like a mess, but may be the only possible solution :-S

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The option you're looking for is `-Werror=objc-method-access`. Clang explicitly tells you this right in the warning message, if you download and compile that gist you posted:

```
% clang test.m -c
test.m:13:21: warning: instance method '-initWithNum:' not found (return type
      defaults to 'id') [-Wobjc-method-access]
  ...theObj = [[MyClass alloc] initWithNum: [NSNumber numberWithInt: 15]];
              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 warning generated.

% clang test.m -Werror=objc-method-access -c  // ta-da!
```

But in real-world situations I agree with all the commenters above: You should fix or suppress *all* compiler warnings. Your build should build cleanly *all* the time. Otherwise, as you so rightly observed, you won't be able to distinguish real bugs from "the usual spam".

FWIW, here's the version of Clang I'm using:

```
$ clang --version
clang version 3.2  (http://llvm.org/git/llvm 1503aba4a036f5394c7983417bc1e64613b2fc77)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin12.2.0
Thread model: posix
```

Comment: As you can see from the full error message I pasted into the gist linked to above, my version of clang *does not* show this annotation. I'll try if it works once I'm near a compiler again.

Comment: When I try this option, I get the following error: clang: warning: unknown warning option '-Werror=objc-method-access'; did you mean '-Werror=objc-cocoa-api'?

Comment: Hm. Well, it was probably added in a more recent version of Clang than the one you're using. If you can't upgrade your toolchain, I guess you're stuck for now. :( For the record, it works fine with Clang version 3.2 (Xcode 4.5 build 4G182).

Comment: I'm always on the latest final release. I can't use betas for shipping products (not as if the final releases aren't beta enough already...). Also: I wouldn't be allowed to talk about betas here.

Comment: And yes, I'm running Version 4.5 (4G182), so whatever version of clang you're using, it's not in the final release. My project's set to "Default compiler (Apple LLVM compiler 4.1)".

Comment: I have Xcode 4.5.2 and also do not get the warning identified in the output. Are you sure you're using a stock Clang and not one you built yourself from source?

Comment: It is one I built from source, but it's definitely versioned "3.2". I've edited my answer to include `--version` information.

Comment: Works in Xcode 4.6. Guess they just hadn't bumped the version number in your build, or you turned on something the official release had off.